# conditional expectation over an area in two-dimensional space

Tags: stochastic-calculus, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, stochastic-integrals

There are two independent and continuous RVs $X$ and $Y$ and there exists a joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ over the set $M = \{(x,y)| 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1-x \}$. Now there exists a function $g(x) = \frac{1}{2} - cx $ that splits $M$ into two sets, namely $A_1 = \{(x,y)|0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le \frac{1}{2} - cx \}$ and $A_2 = \{(x,y)|0 \le x \le 1, \frac{1}{2} - cx \le y \le 1-x  \}$. How do I get $E[Y|A_1] $ and $E[Y|A_2] $ ?

So far I have worked with a simplified problem without $g(x)$. I have calculated $E[Y|X]$ and then next calculated $E[E[Y|X]]$. I have done so by:

- $f_X(x)= \int_0^{1-x} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$,
- $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} $
- $E[Y|X] = \int_0^{1-x} y f_{Y|X}(y|x) dy $
- Say $E[Y|X]$ is a linear transformation $b(X)$ of $X$ and thereby a RV itself that takes on the values $b(0) < w < b(1)$ (or the other way around, depending on $b(X)$)
- $F_{b(X)} = Prob(b(X)<w)$, from this find $f_{b(X)}(b(X))$
- $E[b(X)] = \int_{b(0)}^{b(1)} b(X) f_{b(X)}(b(X))dx $
- Obviously, in accordance with the law of iterated expectations this leads me to $E[Y]$

But where in my calculations would I add $g(x)$ to calculate $E[Y|A_1]$ and $E[Y|A_2]$?

Answer (score 1):

The conditional expectation of a r.v. $X$ given an event $A$ of positive probability is just $$E[X \mid A] = \frac{E[X \cdot 1_A]}{P(A)}.$$
This is especially useful in your case since your events are just $(X,Y)$ landing in a simple region of the plane. Specifically, translating this into an integral with the joint density,
$$
E[Y \mid (X, Y) \in A_1] = \frac{E[Y \cdot 1_{(X, Y) \in A_1}]}{P(A_1)} = \frac{\int_{A_1} y f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy}{\int_{A_1} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy}
$$
and the result is similar for $E[Y \mid (X, Y) \in A_2]$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Is this based on some theorem or just really obvious and I do not see it? :)

Comment: Which part? The first part is (more or less, depending on how one approaches the conditional expectation) just the definition of conditioning on an event. The latter part technically follows from the law of the unconscious statistician (though no one really thinks of that when they take an expectation) for the numerator and the denominator I hope is obvious.